# Fuse ESB/OSGI/Blueprint reading configuration files alphabetically?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi

I experience something rather strange and I would like to know if other people have experienced the same...

I am currently working on a project using jboss fuse (previously fuse esb) and we are using blueprint for our configuration files.
We use property place holders and have the following files under src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint:
blueprint.xml
properties.xml

In blueprint.xml we have something like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.test.MyClass">
    <property name="prop1" value="${my.prop}" />
<∕bean>
```

Then in properties.xml I have this:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="my.properties" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="my.prop" value="true" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

And I obviously have a setter for prop1 (which is a String) in MyClass.

But what I see is that when I deploy this, prop1 is set to "${my.prop}" instead of "true", i.e the variable never gets replaced with its defined value!

But now if I call the properties file aaa_properties.xml, it works!!

Is this a bug in the blueprint container?
Did any one else experience the same behaviour?

Thanks for your feedback :)

JM.

Comment: Is there some way to "include" properties.xml from blueprint.xml, so that the desired order of initialization / loading is enforced?

Comment: Not that I know. AFAIK and from the docs I found only, it is enough to put your xml files in OSGI-INF/blueprint for them to be read by the container. The problem, as I see it at least, is that it looks like the container is reading them and processing them sequentially.

Comment: Well, given we have defined the undocumented behaviour, you could just be pragmatic and a little creative: rename the properties file to `all_properties.xml` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some information about [Blueprint Configuration in Fuse ESB](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeploySimple-Blueprint-Config.html)

It states:

> If you need to place your blueprint configuration files in a non-standard location (that is, somewhere other than OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml), you can specify a comma-separated list of alternative locations in the Bundle-Blueprint header in the manifest

For Example:

```
Bundle-Blueprint: lib/account.xml, security.bp, cnf/*.xml
```

I suggest, can you please give this a try, and specify your xml files here, naturally in the correct ordering.

Comment: I have not tried yet, and even though I would rather call my file aaa_properties, I assume that this might work :)